# OpenMP task and while loop

Tags: c, task, openmp

I have trouble to understand what happens in the following code:

```
/*runs with 4 threads*/
int count_good(item_t* item){
    int n=0;
    int pn[num_thr]; 
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
       pn[omp_get_thread_num()]=0;
       #pragma omp single nowait
       {
       while(item){
           #pragma omp task firstprivate(item)
           {
               if(is_good(item))pn[omp_get_thread_num( )]++;           
           }
       item = item ->next;
       }
     }
    #pragma omp atomic
    n+=pn[omp_get_thread_num()];
    }
    return n;
  }
```

First a parallel region is opened and one thread enters the while loop. This one thread suspends a task every time the loop starts again. The thread pushes the task to the task queue. The other threads can take a task from the queue and execute it. 
Is this correct? Or do i understand it wrongly?

Comment: often task parallelism have some recursive elements in it. Does the function `is_good()` also calls `count_good()`?

Comment: No i don't think so. This is the Solution of an old Exam Question. The Code should be correct (next to typo's). I just wonder what actually happens here. 
I think (always) just one thread generates the tasks and then all threads help to execute the task. They take one by one from the task-queue and execute the tasks (here execute the code line `if(is_good(item))pn[omp_get_thread_num()] ` ). But i'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your model of how tasks work and what this code is trying to do. A single thread is creating tasks (and, then when it has finished doing that also executing them), and other threads are just executing them.

The code is performing a sum reduction by counting the number of "good" items seen by each thread. (In OpenMP 5.0 it could use a task reduction).

Despite what I said before (for which I apologise), this code is correct, since there is an implicit barrier at the end of the single statement. Therefore all threads except the one which executes the single statement wait there, and pickup and execute tasks. Once the thread executing the single statement has exhausted the list (and generated all tasks), it also reaches the barrier and begins to execute tasks. Once all tasks have been executed the barrier can complete. At which point the threads will move on an (atomically) add their contributions into the global sum.

What I had forgotten was the implicit barrier associated with the single statement (which is slightly confusing, since the master statement which seems analogous does not have one!). Since there is one, though, this code is fine. (Aside from a performance issue that the per-thread accumulators will be subject to a lot of false sharing. To avoid that each should be padded to the size of a cache-line [64Bytes on x86]).

Comment: Is it correct, that i have to place  `omp taskwait` outside of the `omp single` routine? But i could also take the calculation of the final result inside the `omp single` Routine without `omp atomic`?
   
     `#pragma omp single nowait
       {
     ....//suspend tasks//....

    #pragma omp taskwait
    n+=pn[omp_get_thread_num()];
   }`

Comment: Sorry the last line should be: `#pragma omp taskwait
    for(int i=0; i<=num_thr; ++i)n+=pn[i];`